# How can I use giter8 `description` field?

Tags: scala, maven, templates, properties-file, giter8

I am using giter8 to create a template for Scala services. Among the fields that I want to use in the template is `description`. However this seems to be [reserved as a Maven property](http://www.foundweekends.org/giter8/template.html#Maven+properties). Any idea how I can work around this?

**These are my current (working) properties:**

```
description = Please answer the following questions:\n

id =
package = com.sebi.$id$
```

Running the template, i get:

```
13:55 $ g8 file://blaze-service-template.g8/

Please answer the following questions:


id []: test
package [com.sebi.test]:

Template applied in ./.
```

**This is what i want to achieve:**

```
description = Please answer the following questions:\n

id =
package = com.sebi.$id$
description = Please describe $id$
```

Running the template, i get:

```
13:56 $ g8 file://blaze-service-template.g8/

context [anonymous] 1:17 attribute id isn't defined
Please describe


context [anonymous] 1:17 attribute id isn't defined
Please describe

id []: test
package [com.sebi.test]:

Template applied in ./.
```

Somehow, using `description` as a custom field breaks giter8.

**If i use `_description` as a custom field, it works:**

```
14:00 $ g8 file://blaze-service-template.g8/

Please answer the following questions:


id []: test
package [com.sebi.test]:
_description [Please describe test]: A stackoverflow Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example

Template applied in ./.
```

**If i use `_description` for the required field, i get:**
    14:05 $ g8 file://blaze-service-template.g8/

```
context [anonymous] 1:17 attribute id isn't defined
Please describe

_description [Please answer the following questions:
]:
```

Comment: What do you mean by "reserved"? The linked example shows usage of `maven(...)`, it's not about `description` field. Please, explain better what you're trying to do and what doesn't work as expected.

Comment: @laughedelic `description` on the first line seems to be a requirement. If i replace it with `desc`, for example, my template breaks: 
`des [Please answer the following questions:  [there_is_actually_a_new_line_here]
]:`.

Comment: `description` on the first line _is not_ a requirement for a giter8 template. I don't understand the code that you post. Why are there two `description`s? Please, prepare a minimal template for your problem. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @laughedelic thanks for your patience, made some changes to the question. It's not really minimal, but i hope its complete and verifiable

Comment: Now the problem is clear! I think this is a bug in giter8 and it has been [reported](https://github.com/foundweekends/giter8/issues/99).